# Dynamic RecyclerView Not Populating Data

Tags: android, xml, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have switched from a ListView to a RecyclerView, and I use data from Firebase to dynamically add RecyclerView items. However, I am unable to successfully generate a RecyclerView.

Currently, the screen is blank and no CardView items are being added to the view. I am assuming there is an issue with my RecyclerView adapter.

My listener, I add to the mCommentArrayList here and then later pull from this data in my RecyclerView Adapter:

```
  mUpdateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            setImage(dataSnapshot);
            setQuestion(dataSnapshot);
            createInitialCommentIDArray(dataSnapshot);
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildrenCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll; i++) {
                String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                Log.v("COMMENT_ID", "The comment ID is " + commentID);
                String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                Log.v("USER_ID", "The user ID is " + userID);
                mCommentArrayList.add(0 , new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        protected ImageView userAvatar;
        protected TextView userID;
        protected TextView userComment;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            userAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image_avatar);
            userID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
            userComment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_comment);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Comments> myDataset) {
        mCommentArrayList = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.individual_comment, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.userComment.setText(mCommentArrayList.get(position).getUserComment());
        holder.userID.setText(mCommentArrayList.get(position).getUserID());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll;
    }
}
```

Comment: i see in your `getItemCount()` you return `mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll`. but i don't see where you declare the `mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll` in `MyAdapter`.

Comment: I know for sure that isn't the issue, but thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

In your getItemCount() of `RecycleViewAdapter`, you should return the list datasource size

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCommentArrayList.size();
}
```

Comment: I also think my ViewHolder is incorrect, as I don't think the sizs in my getItemCount() method is inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

The main issue dealt with my findViewByID() method.

```
     public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        userAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image_avatar);
        userID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
        userComment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_comment);
    }
```

I used v.findViewByID() to resolve the problem and eliminate all data population issues I was experiencing.